# How do I connect ADSL modem to cable internet

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I have  a TP-Link TD-W8901G and cable internet. When I connect the cable Internet via an RJ45 cable, my PC has Internet, but when I want to use wireless it can't connect to my laptop.

What should I do?

Comment: Why can't you connect? Can you give more specifics? Is the laptop connecting to your wireless network but just not able to access the internet? Or is it having trouble evening connecting to your wireless network?

Comment: yes,It connect to my laptop but not to able to access to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a wireless network setup on your ADSL modem? If you do not, set one up. You can find your modem address by typing ipconfig from the cmd line. Open a web browser and type the address for the gateway.    If you do have a wireless network can your laptop see it?  If it can but you are unable to connect, what is the security type on the network, some older laptops do not support WPA2 and new security protocols.